# Set minimum OS version for a major OS version while allowing versions of a previous OS as well?

Tags: ios

There are issues plaguing my application when ran on iOS 8.0(.1 and .2 as well), but they may be resolved with iOS 8.1. The app works great on iOS 7 though. I would like to require a minimum of iOS 8.1 to run the app, unless they're running iOS 7 they should be allowed to use the app with any version of iOS 7. Is there any way to specify that, or will I need to just tell people to update to 8.1 when they contact me with problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done. You need to make your app work better with iOS 8.0.x or do as you said - tell people to update. Who knows, 8.0.3 could fix all of your problems.

Either way, there is no mechanism that allows an app to support all but some specific version in the middle of the Deployment Target / Base SDK range.